# Postgres function to check if something is null

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
Select
   id,
   username,
   is_null(email) AS has_email,
FROM
  users
;
```

I want to write the above query, but instead of returning the email, I only want it to return whether there is an email. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Why do you consider an email that is `null` to be a sign that there *is* an email? Don't you rather want to test for "not null"?

Comment: This is all documented in the manual btw: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Select
   id,
   username,
   email IS NOT NULL AS has_email
FROM
   users
;
```

Edit: changed `IS NULL` to `IS NOT NULL`